# Can't delete table in different schema from Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I try to drop my tables in Apache ignite.
For example;

```
drop table if exists city
```

The code is working for PUBLIC schema but I couldn't delete tables from other schemas.

> The error says 'Failed to parse query. Table "PRODUCT" not found;'

Here is the screenshot of my PowerShell?

[image: apache ignite PowerShell delete table]

How can I delete the tables belong the different schemas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify it:

```
drop table "Product".PRODUCT;
```

You need to do the same thing whenever you reference tables in different schemas, for example with a JOIN.

Comment: Thanks Stephen but I get this error now: 'Error: DROP TABLE can only be executed on PUBLIC schema.' –

Comment: @alamar do you have any idea?